# No spaces in input, output and save

Tags: python

I'm building a CMD type application which asks user for their wanted username, password.
And only one thing that leaved me worried is what if the user types their username as - "Banana Money 610" How could I make those spaces not to be allowed? I researched the forum, and found out this - That I could use some type of  `print(input("Please input a command: ").upper().replace(" ", ""))` This is an example. So how I use this on all of those lines? I mean, I need to save those to a MySQL If is it possible, I wanted to make a local save, but I think instead I'm going to use a MySQL if that's possible. But question is it?

```
name = input("~ Please enter Your name below\n")
password = getpass.getpass("~ Please pick a password, for user - {n}\n".format(n=name))
print("~ Your password is - " + password)
city = input('~ Where are you from?\n* NOTE - You should type correctly. * account recovery.\n')
gmail = input("~ Please add your GMAIL Address.\n")
```

Comment: What's the problem with spaces?

Comment: I can't allow any spaces in password, username, gmail. After all of that information will be inputed,system gonna save it so it will be save in format like username -  "Banana Money 610", password = "BananaWay 65160 asg". I need it to be  "BananaMoney610", "BananaWay6516 asg"

Comment: Yes, and I'm asking you: Why? Why can't you allow spaces?

Answer (score 1):

To piggy-back on Virmundi: you can try something like this for handling that requirement:

```
while True:
    name = input("~ Please enter Your name below\n")
    if " " in name:
        print("Names Must Not Contain The Space (" ") Character")
    else:
        print("thanks")
        break
# Name doesn't have a space. Go on with your life.
```

Comment: That sound's good, I didn't think'ed about this method, but thanks!

Comment: I agree that this answer provides a solid example.

Comment: After doing second line with password, I get a error -     continue not properly in loop

Comment: What is this `continue` doing in your code?  It is redundant. You already have a `while True`.

Comment: What should i use instead continue?

Comment: @Bazingaa The `continue` is for loop control. Basically, it reads, "continue this indefinite loop until the exit condition is met. When it is, print thanks and exit out of the indefinite loop.

Comment: @dsb4k8: Your code will work even without continue. Comment it out and try it. This is because after printing `"Names Must Not Contain The Space (" ") Character"`, the control will go out of the if else and while condition is still True and so the while loop will be executed again.

Comment: @Bazingaa, You're right! I guess old habits die hard. Thanks for the correction :)

Answer (score 0):

You would simply add them to the end like so:

```
name = input("~ Please enter Your name below\n").upper().replace(" ", "")
```

This will strip all spaces out of this input

For passwords, all you need to do is add `password=password.upper().replace(" ", "")` below the `getpass.getpass` command.

```
password = getpass.getpass("~ Please pick a password, for user - {n}\n".format(n=name))
password = password.upper().replace(" ", "")
print("~ Your password is - " + password)
```

Comment: Im using other function as getpass.getpass

Comment: Try adding `password=password.upper().replace(" ", "")` directly below `password = getpass.getpass("~ Please pick a password, for user - {n}\n".format(n=name))` That should delete spaces out of it

Comment: Thanks JROS, for your advance to help! This is exactly what i wanted to do, but instead i gonna use that other, to show user, that he can't use any symbols or spaces.